# .net Task Scalability Problems

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, multitasking

I have an application which launches multiple tasks (1000+) and should hopefully scale well into the 10K+ task area. These tasks are launched gradually at a rate of ~100 per minute. Each task is downloading some data piece by piece, buffering it, and saving it.

I have one simple monitor loop (also a task):

```
While 1
    console.writeline("STILL RUNNING! Tasks:" & task_count & " Threads:" Process.ThreadCount)
    await task.delay(500)
End While
```

At ~3K tasks, everything runs fine. At ~5K tasks, everything starts hitting the fan. The await task.delay(500) starts taking **minutes** to execute. Application thread count starts jumping from 100 to 300 randomly. Everything starts freezing and hanging. Download speed goes to 0. Disk write speed goes to 0. Even CPU usage goes to 0, normally it's at ~10%.

So to finally solve this issue, I simply split my application up into 5 separate process limited to 1k tasks each. If i need more, i just spin up a new process. To communicate i have another central process that they all communicate with, using thousands of WCF named pipes that stay open for hours if I want.

But it works! Splitting into multiple processes delivers significantly better performance than having too many tasks in one process. I haven't actually changed anything inside the code that the tasks execute. I simply split the tasks up into multiple processes, and everything is dandy.

Isn't the whole idea behind tasks to abstract threads and make efficient concurrency easy? Why does it seem to scale so poorly in a single process that i had to split it up in a few?

Comment: I did try configuring SetMinThreads and SetMaxThreads, but they didn't help. The default "MaxThreads" was never close to being hit, and MinThreads controls the point at which there would be a 500ms delay between thread creation. My tasks were never created in bursts, they were created gradually.

Comment: From your description, I suspect you're using Delegate Tasks that call blocking methods. Since most of what you're doing is I/O, consider changing these to be Promise Tasks using asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 2):

Because using bare tasks is hard.

Starting thousands of tasks at the same time is almost always not the optimal solution. There are better options on top of the TPL like PLINQ and TPL Dataflow.

Let's take dataflow for example. You can create a block that does some part of your process. Configure an appropriate degree of parallelism and start posting items into it (you can also bound its size to limit memory usage). Instead of creating thousands of tasks you limit the amount of running tasks which should reduce scheduling overhead and improve the efficiency of your resource usage.

Here's an example:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Item>(
    item => ProcessItem(item),
    new ExecutionDataflowOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 });

foreach (var item in GetItems())
{
    block.Post(item);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

At the end if your processes are all running on the same machine they are using the same resources (i.e. CPU cores and networking stack). It means that by improving the efficiency of your single process you can achieve similar results.